# A topological criterion for connectedness of a semi-ample divisor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

I have a half page long proof of the following statement, and I would like to know if this is (a corollary of) a  well known statement. Maybe there is a reference or a three lines proof?

**Statement.** Suppose $D$ is a semi-ample divisor in a connected complex projective variety $X$. Suppose that $[D]\cap [D]\ne 0\in H^4(X, \mathbb R)$, then $D$ is connected.

Comment: You can replace $D$ by $mD$ for any natural number $m$ without affecting the hypotheses or conclusion, so WLOG assume $D$ is basepoint-free. Then it is the pullback of an ample divisor $A$ by a morphism $f:X \rightarrow Y$ with connected fibres. If $\text{dim} Y>1$, any ample divisor on $Y$ is connected, hence so is its pullback by $f$. If $\text{dim} Y=1$ then $D \cdot D=0$ since $A \cdot A=0$.

Comment: Artie, thanks for your comment. Why $f: X\to Y$ has connected fibres?

Comment: Dear aglearner, if $f: X \rightarrow Y$ doesn't have connected fibres, can't we replace it by its Stein factorisation $g: X \rightarrow Z$? Maybe I am missing something...

Comment: Artie, I think you right. Thank you! This reasoning is considerably simpler than what I had in mind.

Comment: On the other hand, there was a comment by ulrich which said essentially the same thing as mine, which was then deleted. That makes me worry I've overlooked something...